# What does the last column in the MIDI Setup say?

Tags: audio, microphone, midi

I'm trying to configure my microphone in the Audio MIDI Setup app. When configuring a microphone, the last two columns are cut off. The 2nd-to-last column is probably Mute. What's the last column that says "Th..."? There's no way to expand the column, and there's no tooltip when you hover over it. I've also grepped the application folder, but it doesn't return a localization file or anything:  `grep -aiIr mute '/System/Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup.app/'`

[image: Audio MIDI Setup Screenshot]

Can anyone figure out what the "Th..." column does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the accessibility option for spoken content, it read it as "Thru"

It looks like if you have it checked, it will pass the microphone's input through your output so that you can hear what your mic is picking up. Something that'd be useful for monitoring live recording.

Its apparently only enabled if your mic supports it, and I don't have one that does, so I couldn't test it.